# How to pull the thumbnail for a video in azure media services

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

Is it possible to pull the png thumbnail for a video from the manifest url?  I have videos encoded using Azure Media Services.  The thumbnail png files are being created and stored in the blob during the transform.  However, I'm not sure how I can retrieve these client side.  I would like to display thumbnails for a list of videos and allow the user to select a video based on the thumbnail image.

Given the collection of manifest urls:

https://[Account].streaming.media.azure.net/[Locator Id]/Export.ism/manifest

Is it possible to pull a list of thumbnails with only this information?

Comment: did you check https://github.com/harshalawasthi/ConnectorDocs/blob/9a52d063a6fd541d2b54df74d2cd532fa122fb81/articles/media-services/media-services-video-summarization.md

Answer (score 0):

From all the documents, there is no relevant content that can directly parse manifest urls.

*Normal method：*

1. Get the container by asset name, and then get the files in the container.
2. Analyze the files in the container and find the thumbnail file.

Currently it is not possible to get more information through locator_id, there is no official REST API to use.

*Suggest:*

During development, when uploading files and processing videos, save the file path of the manifest file, thumbnail file and other files that need to be stored in the database field. This can reduce a lot of unnecessary trouble.

*Tryable methods (not tested)*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/video-indexer/video-indexer-use-apis#subscribe-to-the-api

https://api-portal.videoindexer.ai/

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to pull the thumbnail file that you created via the manifest file. The thumbnail files you have created are completely independent from the manifest file.